# Импортирование определенных таблиц из mysql БД

Tags: mysql, импорт

```
cat backup.sql | mysql -umyname -pmypass mydbname .... (как указать таблицы table1 table2)
```

Comment: В рамках показанного - никак. SQL-дамп - это для MySQL-сервера просто пачка последовательных запросов. И к таблицам эти запросы не привязаны от слова "совсем", а на стадии их выполнения - уже поздно. Простейшее решение - развернуть дамп во временную БД и потом переместить в рабочую только нужные таблицы. Это в случае, если таблицы и данные в БД уже есть, и надо обновить только часть из них. Иначе - просто развернуть весь бэкап, а потом удалить лишнее. Разумеется, всё это в том случае, если нет возможности повлиять на СОЗДАНИЕ дампа - исключить ненужные таблицы проще именно тогда.

Comment: Спасибо за идею с временной БД! Так наверное и поступлю.